# CXF-SOAP gradle-plugin that works in java-11?

Tags: cxf, gradle-plugin, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin, wsgen

We have a CXF-SOAP service built with gradle,
and trying to migrate it from java-8 to java-11.

Is there any cxf-plugin for gradle available, that works under java-11?

Or any demo/example of a cxf/soap-application that works under java-11 would also be helpful, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading cxf to 3.3.x as earlier versions are not compatible with java 11.

Refer below for details
https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html